# Google console showing 0 supported devices for android wear

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-manifest, wear-os

When I try to upload my APK in Google play developer console then it gives me 0 supported devices. This application is developed for android wear. I have tried to look into the manifest file and didn't find any problem in that.

**Wear AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.util.uni.student" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="22"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0"
        />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/st_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault" >
        <activity
            android:name=".studentBroadcastActivity"
            android:label="student" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".studentReceiver"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.util.uni.student.SHOW_NOTIFICATION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:

[image: Screenshot from developer console]

I have made the changes you mentioned. And now I have two project one is an empty mobile module contains a reference of my wearable module. But, still getting 0 compatible device.

**Wear Build.Gradle Script**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.util.uni.student"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

**Mobile Build.Gradle Script**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.util.uni.student"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

**Mobile AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.util.uni.student">

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Edit # 2:**

I have updated the mobile AndroidManifest.xml and removed the watch feature from that. Now, it's showing the devices but not showing watch as a device.

[image]

Comment: Probably all these devices have android 4.4w. Try to change android:minSdkVersion="20"

Comment: I have changed that to 20 and then 19 but in both cases didn't work.

Comment: Updated my answer based on the extra detail.  watch feature only needs to be included in wear manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your updated question your mobile manifest does not need the watch feature.  This should be only included in the watch app.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />
```

**Original Answer before clarification which may help others**

You cannot upload just the watch application to the Play Store, it needs to be included within a mobile apk file, even if that's just an empty container.

Your should have a mobile build.gradle that includes the wearable app as a dependency, my example below refers to a seperate module called wear which is part of my project and contains the watch application.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
wearApp project(':wear')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:7.3.0'
...
}
```

[See official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/packaging.html)

Comment: You mean  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />... So, yes I have removed that and after that it has shown me devices but my watch wasn't there.

Comment: Your play store listing is now correct, it only shows the mobile devices your app can work on.  Consider the wear part as an optional extra that the play store does not give details for.